# Block Other peoples speakers

Tags: audio, bluetooth, airplay

My flat mate bought a smart speaker and it pops up on my output settings...

I hate that, I never paired with it why is it on my computer as an option?

I feel like this violates several levels of privacy...

And I always need to be extra careful before changing output devices because of this and is annoying me beyond my rational limits  :|

My name is not Herman why is this even an option to me?

[image]

Comment: As long as a device is broadcasting your Mac can see it.

Comment: thanks I hate it...

Comment: You could ask your flatmate to power down the speaker when it is not in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My flat mate bought a smart speaker and it pops up on my output settings...
>
> I hate that, I never paired with it why is it on my computer as an option?

Unfortunately, you cannot block your Mac from discovering other devices that are broadcasting. As long as a device is broadcasting, your Mac is going to search and discover it.  This is  because the Mac is constantly listening for other devices that are broadcasting their services.

In order for you, not to see these devices, they should be powered down when not in use. The moment with device is paired with something else like another computer. It will stop broadcasting its services but,  once it’s disconnected it will broadcast so you can connect to it.

Comment: looks like there is nothing I can do, other than switching to linux or something like that xD

if I place the computer on a different network, would that hide the Airplay device?

Comment: I doubt it because my Mac picks up the neighbors airplay devices and we are on completely different networks.